# codeigniter: curl with facebook graph

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm trying to get the large image of the user using his facebook id,
this is my try;

```
$fb_id = 100007869520485;

$url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_id.'/picture?type=large';

echo $this->curl->simple_get($url);
```

but it's not worked!
any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your request url changes into wrong format:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/1.0000786952048E+14/picture?type=large
                          +-----------------+
```

Place the `100007869520485` inside `""` so that it treated as a string. Otherwise `php` automatically transforms that large number into scientific mode number.

```
$fb_id = "100007869520485";
```

UPDATE:: With curl:

```
$fb_id = "100007869520485";
$url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_id.'/picture?type=large';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print "$result\n";
```

Comment: `$fb_id = 100007869520485;`

`echo $this->curl->simple_get("http://graph.facebook.com/$fb_id/picture?type=large");` 
**not worked :(**

Comment: Do what I said. Where is the `"` ? Use this: `$fb_id = "100007869520485";`

Comment: Also this: `echo $this->curl->simple_get("http://graph.facebook.com/100007869520485/picture?type=large");` not worked

Comment: Enable redirection handling with your `simple_get`. Check my updated answer that returns image!

Comment: That is the image that you wanted. Just save the `$result` into a `jpg` using `file_put_contents` or similar function.

Comment: @زهيرطه did you able to save the image into a file??